# switch выбор перехода по значению и по условию, как?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть блок switch например:

```
private int State
switch (State)
{
    case -1:
        какие то операции
    case 0>: ??????
```

На больше нуля ругается, подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать.

Comment: Интересный вопрос, но наверное так нельзя

Comment: Не знаю, как в C#, но в остальных С-подобных языках в case могут быть только целочисленные значения и больше ничего.

Comment: а в шарпе еще и строки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [int.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ky8xsk.aspx):

```
int result = State.CompareTo(0);
switch (result)
{
case 1 : //>0
    break;
default: //все остальное
    break;
}
```

Comment: т.е. если у меня result будет содержать значение 500 к примеру то выполнится case 1 ?

Comment: result не будет содержать 500. CompareTo возвращает 1, 0 или -1

Comment: Все, понял. Спасибо!

Comment: @ganouver Согласен, но только для тех случаев, когда достаточно сравнения с одним значением и трех возвращаемых значений (больше-равно-меньше) :)

Comment: @barber так вроде того и просили.

Answer (score 5):

Если не устраивают конструкции с if, я бы предложил нечто такое:

```
enum ComparisonResult
{
    IS_MINUS_ONE,
    GREATER_THAN_ZERO,
    OTHER_CASE
}

ComparisonResult result = ComparisonResult.OTHER_CASE;
result = (state == -1) ? ComparisonResult.IS_MINUS_ONE : result;
result = (state > 0) ? ComparisonResult.GREATER_THAN_ZERO : result;

switch(result)
{
     case ComparisonResult.IS_MINUS_ONE:
          // ...
     case ComparisonResult.GREATER_THAN_ZERO:
          // ...
     case ComparisonResult.OTHER_CASE:
          break;
}
```

Comment: Вариант кстати, а вот это

    ComparisonResult result = ComparisonResult.OTHER_CASE;
    result = (state == -1) ? ComparisonResult.IS_MINUS_ONE : result;
    result = (state > 0) ? ComparisonResult.GREATER_THAN_ZERO : result;

можно вынести в проперти.

Comment: Как забавное решение да, ставлю +, но для практического применения - извращение ужасное.

Comment: Да... из 2-х строк в if такая простыня !!!

C# ? Мелкософт, то-то я смотрю у них такие здоровенные программы.

Comment: значит кривые программы смотрите

>GREATER_THAN_ZERO

никогда не пишите капсом что-либо кроме констант! ``GreaterThenZero`` намного лучше выглядит

Comment: @Valeriy Karchov Согласен, можно в property или даже в метод расширения:

public static ComparisonResult MyCompare(this int state)
{
    ComparisonResult result = ComparisonResult.OTHER_CASE;
    result = (state == -1) ? ComparisonResult.IS_MINUS_ONE : result;
    result = (state > 0) ? ComparisonResult.GREATER_THAN_ZERO :  result;
    return result;
}

@avp Можно и на if всё построить, но вопрос-то был о switch.

@Spectre Мне кажется, это вопрос личных предпочтений :) Главное, чтобы подход был единообразный :)

Comment: switch тут не к месту.

Answer (score 4):

Я где-то читал, что switch при количестве кейсов больше 7 компилируется в словарь, сопоставляющий значениям проверяемого выражения ссылки на место в исполняемом коде. Поэтому, по идее, этот оператор эффективнее, чем множество if, если много вариантов условия, но эти варианты должны быть константами, т.к. все они должны быть известны на этапе компиляции.

Если надо совместить switch с другими условиями, то можно сделать так

```
switch (someExpression)
{
  case val1:
    Do1();
    break;

  case val2:
    Do2();
    break;

  ...
  default:
    if (someExpression2(someExpression))
    {
      Do3();
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: на счёт словарей хорошая идея:
<pre>
Dictionary<int, Action> dict = new Dictionary<int, Action<int>>();
...
dict.Add(-1,Do1(1));
dict.Add(0,Do2());
...
dict[State]();// Вызовится нужный Action
...
</pre>

Comment: Делегат медленнее, чем ссылка на место в коде (явно на C# такое, понятное дело, не сделать, даже оператор goto не позволяет использовать метку как переменную). Лучше базовый класс с виртуальным методом. Это быстрее, чем делегат и чем интерфейс.